# Getting path for physical SD card in Oreo (API26)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm writing a Android app. If I identify a physical SD card (see later the code), I would offer to save the files data to the card (the data are 300MB-800MB). I would use the "app-specific directory", that the system deletes when the user uninstalls the app. If I cannot identify the SD using the code, simply I don't offer the possibility.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 (but same problem in 3.1) and AVD (SD in external file).

Until API25 the following code identifies correctly the SD card:

```
String mySDPath = "";
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21 ) {
   File[] ExternalStorage = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs( myContext, null );
   Emulated = true;
   for( int i = 0; i < ExternalStorage.length; i++ ) {
      Emulated = Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated( ExternalStorage[i] );
      if( !Emulated ) {
         mySDPath = ExternalStorage[i].getAbsolutePath();
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Starting from AVD API26 the "physical SD" is not recognized.
After the line:

```
File[] ExternalStorage = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs( myContext, null );
```

I see in the debugger for API25:

```
ExternalStorage[0] = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app/files
ExternalStorage[1] = /storage/10E7-191B/Android/data/my.app/files
```

but for API26 only:

```
ExternalStorage[0] = /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/my.app/files
```

Using Android Studio "Device File Explorer" I see:

- [API25](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBQHL.png)
- [API26](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMRMh.png)

Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() does deliver path to removable SD card on Oreo. So you can use it. But if you really want to make a good app then use Storage Volumes to grab the removable SD card. Or Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Both latter let you write everywhere on the card.

Comment: Many thanks. About Storage Volumes: but if I use it, when the app is removed the data is deleted? I need this behavior... About getExternalFilesDirs(): I know that getExternalFilesDirs() should working... and it's true in my tests until API25 (in AVD). But in API26 (same app, same configuration in AVD) it's not working. Have you tried it in API26? Regards.

Comment: I do not know those api numbers by head. I said it works up to Android 8. And of course i use a real device.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry: API26 is Android 8.0, API25 is Android 7.1. If you tried on a real device and it's working, maybe the problem is the emulator in Android Studio.

Comment: @JJC I am facing the same issue on API 26 emulator. I tried on a real API 26 device and it works just like API 25. This is defiantly an emulator issue.

Comment: Not working on emulator of API 27, not sure of real device, that is what brought me here